# why i get wrong argc value in android ndk app?

Tags: android, android-ndk

the c file is **mytest.c**:

```
include "stdio.h"
include "stdlib.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        int i=1;
        i+=2;
        printf("Hello, world (i=%d)!\n", i);
        printf("argc=%d\n", argc);

        exit(0);
}
```

and the **Makefile** is:

```
APP := mytest
ROOT := /opt
INSTALL_DIR := /data/local/tmp
NDK_PLATFORM_VER := 8
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT := $(ROOT)/android-ndk-r5b
ANDROID_NDK_HOST := linux-x86
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT := /opt/android-sdk-linux_x86
PREBUILD := $(ANDROID_NDK_ROOT)/toolchains/arm-eabi-4.4.0/prebuilt/$(ANDROID_NDK_HOST)
ANDROID_NDK_BIN := $(PREBUILD)/bin
ANDROID_NDK_INC := $(ANDROID_NDK_ROOT)/platforms/android-$(NDK_PLATFORM_VER)/arch-arm/usr/include
ANDROID_NDK_LIB := $(ANDROID_NDK_ROOT)/platforms/android-$(NDK_PLATFORM_VER)/arch-arm/usr/lib

CC := $(ANDROID_NDK_BIN)/arm-eabi-gcc
CPP := $(ANDROID_NDK_BIN)/arm-eabi-g++
LIBCRT := $(ANDROID_NDK_LIB)/crtbegin_dynamic.o
CFLAGS := -fno-short-enums -I$(ANDROID_NDK_INC)
LFLAGS := -nostdlib -Wl,--entry=main,-rpath-link=$(ANDROID_NDK_LIB),-dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker,-rpath=/system/lib $(ANDROID_NDK_LIB)/crtbegin_dynamic.o
LDFLAGS = -lgcc -lc -L$(ANDROID_NDK_LIB)

all: $(APP)

OBJS += $(APP).o

$(APP): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(ANDROID_NDK_LIB)/crtend_android.o -o $@

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) -c $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

install: $(APP)
        $(ANDROID_SDK_ROOT)/platform-tools/adb push $(APP) $(INSTALL_DIR)/$(APP)
        $(ANDROID_SDK_ROOT)/platform-tools/adb shell chmod 777 $(INSTALL_DIR)/$(APP)

shell:
        $(ANDROID_SDK_ROOT)/platform-tools/adb shell

run:
        $(ANDROID_SDK_ROOT)/platform-tools/adb shell $(INSTALL_DIR)/$(APP)

clean:
        @rm -f $(APP).o $(APP)
```

when i run make && make install && make run, the result is puzzled to me:

```
Hello, world (i=3)!
**argc=33632**
```

Comment: Wow, very strange! Are you sure you're not passing any args? Check your IDE's options!

Comment: has no args. I am not use IDE, only do it in shell

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here.
Is it supposed to be a standard c program which you want to use in the adb shell?
Or is it an application you want to use from your phone via normal means?

Concerning the first guess you should probably debug the program with gdb on the device or use some code to print the env. It seems like some pointer is overwriting your argc or the shell is not setting argc correctly.

Concerning the other guess I would say you are approaching the use of the NDK from a wrong direction. Read up on how to use the NDK.

Comment: I want to use it in my phone. evenly, i run it in terminal of phone directly, it also could not get argc value, what overwriting my argc?

Comment: As lhw states, you have to run a debugger (like gdb) to see what's overwriting argc.

Comment: maybe the problem of crtbegin_dynamic.o? Need i compile crtbegin_dynamic.S myself, and link to my application?

Comment: Rewrite Android.mk file, use ndk_build, app has no problem, so shouldn't use this way!!!